# Can I unbox a string?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

What I understand unboxing is when I take a object and unbox it to *valuetype* like the MSDN example:

```
int i = 123;
object o = i;  
o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing
```

So I just was thinking, can a string be unboxed? I think, No it can't because there is no *valuetype* that can represent a string. Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423452/boxing-and-unboxing-in-int-and-string

Comment: @Baboon I read that question before I posted mine. I think my question was more tight realted to the fact that a string cannot be unboxed. The other is more general in my point of view =) Thanks for keeping SO clean anyway ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're right. A string can't be unboxed because only value types are subject to boxing and unboxing; a string is a reference type.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused some days ago and start reading about it so it was just a control question so I got it ;-) Thanks !

Comment: So a string can neither be boxed as this example says in the first line: http://johnbarshinger.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/c-boxing-and-unboxing-cast-as-convert-parse-tryparse/