# C# Why i can call object extension methods on constants?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# why I can call

```
var intStr = 1.ToString();
var strStr = "1".ToString();
```

1 and "1" are constant literals so why `object.ToString()` is not causing errors?

Comment: Why should they cause errors? Why would it need to be any different than a variable of the exact same type?  Also, `ToString` is not an extension method, it's an instance method.  *Big* difference.

Comment: @Servy I was in false impression that constants are different than variables :) and thanks for pointing out that ToString() is an instance method.

Comment: Constants *are* different from variables. Variables are *storage locations* and their values can *change*, which is why they are called "variables".  Constants are *values* that do not change, which is why they are called "constants".  What is unclear from your question is why you believe that the *constancy of the storage of the value* is relevant to *whether it is legal to call a method with the value as the receiver*. Since you've not told us that, I'll hypothesize why you might believe this to be incorrect in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why I can call object extension methods on constants?

Those aren't extension methods.

> `1` and `"1"` are constants so why `ToString()` is not causing errors?

Your question asks "why not" *without ever explaining why you think this should be a problem in the first place*. When asking questions of this form in the future please say why you think the operation ought to be disallowed.

So let's try to read your mind.  Here's a question you could have asked:

> `1` and `"1"` are *literals* but the left hand side of a dot must be a *symbol*, like `x`, so why is  `1.ToString()` not causing errors?

The supposition is incorrect. The thing on the left hand side of a member access dot must be an expression. There are restrictions on that expression; for example, it cannot be a void-returning method call. But there is no restriction on it being a literal.

Here's another question you could have asked:

> `1` is a *constant of value type* but the receiver of a method of a value type must be a variable, because the `this` in the method is a `ref` to a variable. So why is  `1.ToString()` not causing errors?

If the receiver of a method call is of a value type and the `this` has to be of `ref` type but the receiver expression is not classified as a variable then the compiler copies the value to a temporary variable and passes a `ref` to that variable.

This means that if the method mutates the variable, the mutation is lost because it is performed on a copy. This is yet another reason why mutable value types are a bad practice. It is easy to lose a mutation accidentally!

Here's another question you could have asked:

> `1.` is the beginning of a float, double or decimal literal; the thing that comes next should be a digit. So why is  `1.ToString()` not causing errors?

The question makes an incorrect supposition. The lexer *checks* whether the thing that follows the dot is a digit; if it is then it keeps lexing the literal as a float, double or decimal. (Which it is will be determined by the suffix, if any.)  If the thing that follows the dot is not a digit then the lexer lexes the dot as a member access dot and starts lexing a new token for the `ToString`.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm a beginner in C# and still need to know many concepts. Sorry, and next time I will try to explain my question better for this time here it is.
I did not know that in C# constant literals are also treated as object (System.Object) or more clearly previously I believe that constant literals as only values stored in memory and variables points at those values have types. So in the case of var intStr = 1.ToString(); I thought 1 is just 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 stored in memory and intStr is a variable of type int and have above binary value as its data.

Comment: @EricLippert There is nothing wrong in your answer I have learn new things from your answer and also now I know what to think and do when asking a question. :) Thanks

Comment: @SandeepKumar: Your belief is completely correct! A constant of value type is just a bit pattern, but *the C# compiler knows that the type is int*.  So when you call `1.ToString()` the compiler says "make a temporary variable of type int, copy `1` into that temporary variable, and then invoke `Int32.ToString` with a ref to that variable as `this`."

Answer (score 5):

They are initialised from constant literals (in the program text), but they are actually objects (in that they are logically treated as objects), and all objects implement `ToString()`

So `1` is of type `System.Int32`.

Therefore you can call `ToString()` for them.

The IL generated for this is something like this:

```
L_0001: ldc.i4.1 
L_0002: stloc.1 
L_0003: ldloca.s CS$0$0000
L_0005: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
```

Note that the `ldc.i4.1` is a special instruction that pushes a `System.Int32` with value 1 onto the stack. That, specifically, is the instruction that actually "creates" the the `System.Int32` value object.

Also note that although System.Int32 is a value type, it is also treated as an object, so that the following statement is always true:

```
bool isObject = (1 is object);
```

Comment: mm careful ... the literal `1` is an int *value*, which is being boxed to an object prior to having `ToString()` called on it.

Comment: Calling `int.ToString()` doesn't do any boxing - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423452/boxing-and-unboxing-in-int-and-string Note that if it was boxing, the IL would contain the `box` instruction. It doesn't do boxing for `int` because `int` overrides `ToString()`, which prevents boxing from occurring.

Comment: @csj Matthew is correct. The compiler elides the boxing when the value type overrides the method. This is one reason why overriding those methods is a good idea.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Did you perhaps post the wrong link?  That post doesn't explain why calling `ToString` on an `int` doesn't box it.  It talks about both using `ToString` and boxing, but in different contexts.

Comment: @Servy The reply marked as the answer in the link I gave starts "Calling ToString is not boxing. It creates a new string that just happens to contain the textual representation of your int." - that's what I was alluding to. The question I linked asks if `string s = i.ToString();` does any boxing.

Comment: @CSJ: Fun fact: `1.GetType()` does box the int. `GetType` is not virtual and therefore not overridden on `Int32`, and therefore the `this` must be of type `object`, so it is boxed. Of course you would be silly to do this in the first place as `typeof(int)` is more clear.