# What happens in this Boxing example in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

Jon Skeet, has an interesting post titled: "[**Why boxing doesn't keep me awake at night**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx)" where he benchmarks the performance of different ways of outputting an integer value.

I am pretty sure the code below **IS** boxing, but why Jon is considering it **NOT** to be boxing? his example is at the end.

```
int i = 5;
object o = i;
Console.WriteLine("Number is: {0}", o);
```

The example from Jon's page:

```
#if CONSOLE_WITH_BOXING
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i, i, i);            
#elif CONSOLE_NO_BOXING
            object o = i;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", o, o, o);
#elif CONSOLE_STRINGS
            string s = i.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", s, s, s);
```

P.S. [**"boxing and unboxing in int and string"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423452/boxing-and-unboxing-in-int-and-string) does not answer my question.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you just deleted your previous question and reported?

Comment: Yes I did, as it was marked as DUPLICATE, so instead of editting I removed it and posted a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [boxing and unboxing in int and string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423452/boxing-and-unboxing-in-int-and-string)

Comment: Don't repost. Just tell in the original post why you think it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Patrick SO recommends to edit or ask a new question when a question is flagged as duplicate also the "boxing and unboxing in int and string" does not answer my question as mentioned above. :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not the case. A post can be reopened if it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Patrick, I didn't say it can't be reopened/edited, asking a new question is one of the 2 options available which is what I chose. I think it is better to concentrate on the question/answer instead of going on a tangent here

Comment: No. You should not repost. Can you supply a link to meta whether reposting is allowed?

Comment: So let me get this straight: you deleted a question to protest it being marked as a duplicate, then proceeded to repost it? Doesn't that make your reposted question a duplicate of itself? Talk about a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: Without getting too Meta here, it says new question, not the same question again

Comment: @Klors this question is not the "same question" it is a new one which now has an answer! :-)

Comment: @MaYaN: It... is the same question. A new *copy*, but the same question. The fact that it now has an answer is irrelevant. In any case, please don't do this again. It's not allowed, and will only serve to increase your chances of getting banned from asking questions altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock, you may be right! now let's move on :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is boxing, the only difference is on what line it is happening:

not boxing (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0bfz20d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", o, o, o);
```

boxing:

```
object o = i;
```

or consider

three boxing(s):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i, i, i);
```

one boxing:

```
object o = i;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", o, o, o);
```

Comment: perfect! it makes sense.